# Find inconsecutive running values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an sql table like the one attached below

```
+-----+------------+-------+-----+
| ID  |    Name    | Start | End |
+-----+------------+-------+-----+
| 100 | Road one   |     0 | 244 |
| 101 | Road two   |     0 | 300 |
| 101 | Road two   |   300 | 329 |
| 101 | Road two   |   329 | 400 |
| 101 | Road two   |   400 | 380 |
| 102 | Road three |     0 | 120 |
| 102 | Road three |   122 | 175 |
| 102 | Road three |   175 | 222 |
+-----+------------+-------+-----+
```

I need to find all running `Start` and `End` values which are not consecutive for each unique `ID`.

In the above sample 380 is less than 400 which is incorrect while 122 is greater than 120 which is also incorrect as it should be 120 (previous `End` value).

I need a sql script to highlight these values.

Help appreciated

Comment: i can do this very very easily in report builder or even write a small c# app but i need a portable sql script to do this now

Comment: so what..you should atleast show your attempt.

Comment: can u just give me a minute, i will answer my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 and later and you can use LAG function, you can user below query

Setup Data

```
create table #t (ID int, Name varchar(20), Start int , [End] int)

insert into #t values
( 100 , 'Road one'   ,     0 , 244 ),
( 101 , 'Road two'   ,     0 , 300 ),
( 101 , 'Road two'   ,   300 , 329 ),
( 101 , 'Road two'   ,   329 , 400 ),
( 101 , 'Road two'   ,   400 , 380 ),
( 102 , 'Road three' ,     0 , 120 ),
( 102 , 'Road three' ,   122 , 175 ),
( 102 , 'Road three' ,   175 , 222 )
```

Query

```
with cte as (
  select ID, Name, Start, [End]
  , LAG([End]) over (partition by ID order by ID, Start, [End]) PrevEnd
  from #t
)
select ID, Name, Start, [End]
from cte
where Start <> PrevEnd or [End] < Start
```

Result

```
+-----+------------+-------+-----+
| ID  |    Name    | Start | End |
+-----+------------+-------+-----+
| 101 | Road two   |   400 | 380 |
| 102 | Road three |   122 | 175 |
+-----+------------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i was also going for a cte but i did not know about the LAG function. I also had to add `start` and `end` in the `order by` clause and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. You are right, they should be in order by. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
--this select row | 102 | Road three |     0 | 120 |
SELECT * 
FROM table AS t1 
WHERE NOT Exists (SELECT 1 FROM table AS t2 WHERE t2.start = t1.end AND t2.id = t1.id)
AND Exists (SELECT 1 FROM table AS t2 WHERE t2.start > t1.end AND t2.id = t1.id)

--this select row| 102 | Road three |   122 | 175 |
SELECT * 
FROM table AS t1 
WHERE NOT Exists (SELECT 1 FROM table AS t2 WHERE t2.end = t1.start AND t2.id = t1.id)
AND t1.start <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following has the condition that if a previous row exists for the id, then there must be a previous row with the same end:

```
select t.*
from t
where end < start or
      (not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.end = t.start) and
       exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.start < t.start)
      );
```

This covers the possibilities in your question.  I'm not sure if it covers all possibilities.